# HttpClient PutAsync not updating Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple .Net Core Web API with some simple Get, post, put endpoints. I also created a simple Console Client to test the API. The get and post methods work fine although when I test the Put, it does not update the Web API with the new data. I have tested the Web API Put method with swagger and it works fine, so it seems like my Console App Client logic is incorrect. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

edit: weather is an in-memory collection - a List so I do not need to SaveChanges()

Console Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Lab1RestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private static readonly String baseURI = "https://localhost:44347/api/Weather/";

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            try
            {

                //1 GET /api/Weather/
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<WeatherInformation>));
                var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync(baseURI);
                var entries = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as List<WeatherInformation>;
                foreach (var e in entries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");

                //2 GET /api/Weather/
                serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<WeatherInformation>));
                streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync(baseURI + "warning/false");
                entries = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as List<WeatherInformation>;
                foreach (var e in entries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }

                //3 GET /api/Weather/city/Dublin
                serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(WeatherInformation));
                streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync(baseURI + "city/Dublin");
                WeatherInformation weatherinfo = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as WeatherInformation;
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + weatherinfo + "\n");


                // serialise to JSON
                weatherinfo = new WeatherInformation() { City = "Antwerp", Temp = 3, Warning = true, WeatherType = 0, WindSpeed = 22 }; ;             
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(WeatherInformation));
                ser.WriteObject(ms, weatherinfo);

                // read and create string content for POST
                ms.Position = 0;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(sr.ReadToEnd(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


                //4 POST - add new city
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(baseURI, content);
                httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


                //5 update PUT to api/Weather/Dublin - now temp is 10   
                weatherinfo = new WeatherInformation() { City = "Antwerp", Temp = 10, Warning = true, WeatherType = 0, WindSpeed = 22 }; ;               
                var putTask = client.PutAsync(baseURI + "Dublin", content);

            }

            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
            client.Dispose();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The Put action in Web API

```
    // PUT: api/Weather/5
    [HttpPut("{city}")]
    public IActionResult PutUpdateCityWeather(string city, WeatherInformation weatherInfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var record = weather.FirstOrDefault(e => e.City.ToUpper() == city.ToUpper());
            if (record != null)
            {
                record.Temp = weatherInfo.Temp;
                record.Warning = weatherInfo.Warning;
                record.WeatherType = weatherInfo.WeatherType;
                record.WindSpeed = weatherInfo.WindSpeed;

                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In your example you are creating content for the POST method which works fine. But then for the PUT method you are just declaring weatherinfo and content variable was not updated  so you are sending the same information. Also there is an extra ";" on your last weatherinfo assignment.

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint in your PutUpdateCityWeather method? Does it ever get hit?